# What design pattern to use parent and child class with child method?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I have faced this problem many times when I want to build a parent-child relationship class. 
I have a base `AuthenticateRequest` class. In my case, I have 2 child requests but they have own logic to `GetContent()`. 
It doesn't not really fall into [Composite Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern) nor [Liskov Substitution](https://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/solid-class-design-the-liskov-substitution-principle/) as the base method is unique and called.
Which design pattern should I use?

```
public class AuthenticateRequest
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public string Method { get; set; }

    public virtual HttpContent GetContent()
    {
        return new StringContent("");
    }
} 

public class SoapAuthenticateRequest : AuthenticateRequest
{
    public string SoapMethodName { get; set; }

    public string SoapAction { get; set; }

    public string KeyForUserNameParameter { get; set; }

    public string ValueForUserNameParameter { get; set; }

    public string KeyForPasswordParameter { get; set; }

    public string ValueForPasswordParameter { get; set; }

    public override HttpContent GetContent()
    {
        var methodName = this.SoapMethodName;
        var keyUsername = this.KeyForUserNameParameter;
        var keyPwd = this.KeyForPasswordParameter;
        var valueUsername = this.ValueForUserNameParameter;
        var valuePwd = this.ValueForPasswordParameter;
        var soapAction = this.SoapAction ?? @"http://tempuri.org/"; 

        var soap = $@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""><soap:Body><{methodName} xmlns=""{soapAction}""><{keyUsername}>{valueUsername}</{keyUsername}><{keyPwd}>{valuePwd}</{keyPwd}></{methodName}></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

        return new StringContent(soap, Encoding.UTF8, ContentTypes.XmlSoap);
    }
}

public class JsonAuthenticateRequest : AuthenticateRequest
{
    public string SoapMethodName { get; set; }

    public string SoapAction { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> ParameterKeyValues { get; set; }

    public override HttpContent GetContent()
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ParameterKeyValues);
        return new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, ContentTypes.Json);
    }
}

public async Task<AuthenticateResponse> Authenicate(AuthenticateRequest request)
{
    var requestMsg = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri(request.Url),
        Method = new HttpMethod(request.Method.ToString()),
        Content = request.GetContent(),
    };

    var responseMsg = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMsg).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var responseContent = await responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    return new AuthenticateResponse
    {
        Message = responseContent,
        IsSuccess = Regex.Match(responseContent, (string)request.RegexForValidUser).Success
    };
}
```

Comment: Don´t code for (design-)pattern. Any pattern can be right or whrong if it gets the job done. Having said this your question is fairly **opinion-based**, which is why I´m voting to close it.

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you have? its kind of hard to understand what you want. (said in the nicest possible way)

Comment: @HimBromBeere I can't find any similar question on stackoverflow. I hope this question can be a hint to others. The answer can be **opinion-based** or **guideline**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see Factory pattern?

But for your problem, to require the class having his proper implementation. You can just simply use the abstract keyword like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)

```
public abstract class AuthenticateRequest
{    
    public abstract HttpContent GetContent();
} 

public class SoapAuthenticateRequest : AuthenticateRequest
{
    public override HttpContent GetContent()
    {
        // your logic

        return new StringContent(soap, Encoding.UTF8, ContentTypes.XmlSoap);
    }
}

public class JsonAuthenticateRequest : AuthenticateRequest
{
    public override HttpContent GetContent()
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ParameterKeyValues);
        return new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, ContentTypes.Json);
    }
}
```